# In wx.Python, how would I get the window handle (hwnd) to my frame and set its style?

Tags: coding-style, wxpython, hwnd

How can I get a handle to my current window in wx.Python (hWnd) and set it's style to WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY, or can I set this when I initialize the frame?

This question is a result from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941470/wxpython-wont-close-frame-with-a-parent-who-is-a-window-handle)

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
frame.SetExtraStyle(4)
```

Also, `frame.GetHandle()` will return the HWND. But this all sounds pretty hacked up.

Comment: Agreed, but there doesn't seem to be a way to close the window and not have the parent refuse to close later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.Show(True)
self.Show(False)
self.Show(True)
self.GetHandle()
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.